# How to embed a custom close button in top right hand corner of a Ext.MessageBox Sencha Touch 2.0

Tags: button, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, messagebox

I am trying to find a way to get a close (X button) in the top right hand corner of the Ext.MessageBox in Sencha Touch 2.0 so that when you click on the button it closes the MessageBox.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at this nice tutorial:
[Add action buttons to floating sencha touch panels](http://www.swarmonline.com/2011/01/ext-ux-panelaction-add-action-buttons-to-floating-sencha-touch-panels/)

the explanation is for ST1, but it might help you understanding how you could achieve this in ST2.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in config which meets your need, so you have to do it manually.

Note that `Ext.MessageBox` is just a `float` and `modal` `Ext.Container`, so you can customize it like a normal container.

Let's try something like this (you can edit this code live through Sencha Touch 2 documentation here:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox

```
var box = Ext.create('Ext.MessageBox',
                         {
                             id: 'message-box',
                             title: 'title', 
                             message: 'message', 
                             items: [
                                 {
                                 xtype: 'toolbar',
                                 height: '40px',
                                 docked: 'top',
                                 items: [
                                     {xtype: 'spacer'},
                                     {xtype: 'button', 
                                      text: 'X', 
                                      ui: 'plain',
                                      style: {padding: '5px'},
                                      handler: function(){Ext.getCmp('message-box').hide();}
                                     },
                                 ],
                                 }
                             ]
                        });
    box.show();
```

Hope it helps.