# How to use Ext.panel.Panel in sencha touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am using phonegap and sencha touch to build android app.
I have sencha-touch-all.js and sencha-touch.css files included.

And I am using Ext.Carousel and it works nicely.I want to use panel as a overlay for Carousel .If i write `new Ext.Panel` it works. ButExt.panel.Panel is not working it says "TypeError:Ext.panel is undefined" 
Any help?? 
my code is as follows::

```
var overlay = new Ext.panel.Panel({
    overlay: true,
    id:'myPanel',

    width: 400,
    height: 280,
        left: 200,
        top : 18,
        style:'background-color:#00CC33' ,
        cls:'my-panel',
        fullscreen:true,
        draggable : true,
        resizable : true,
        closable : true,

                    items: [
                {
                                  label: 'Name',
                                  xtype: 'textfield',
                                  name:'textField1'
                },
                {
                                  label: 'Email',
                                  xtype: 'emailfield',
                                  name:'textField2'
                },
                {
                                   label: 'Password',
                                   xtype: 'passwordfield',
                                   name:'textField3'

                }
            ]
});

  myCarousel.add(overlay);
```

instead of Ext.panel.panel if i use Ext.Panel it works. But i cant close that panle,which is not giving any close button. But i want my panel to be draggable,resizable and closable.
Is it necessary to use ext.js also along with sencha-touch-all.js??

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer thorgh this link : [How to embed a custom close button in top right hand corner of a Ext.MessageBox Sencha Touch 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733626/how-to-embed-a-custom-close-button-in-top-right-hand-corner-of-a-ext-messagebox)

Writing here :

```
var box = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',
                             {
                                 id: 'message-box',
                                 title: 'title', 
                                 message: 'message', 
                                 items: [
                                     {
                                     xtype: 'toolbar',
                                     height: '40px',
                                     docked: 'top',
                                     items: [
                                         {xtype: 'spacer'},
                                         {xtype: 'button', 
                                          text: 'X', 
                                          ui: 'plain',
                                          style: {padding: '5px'},
                                          handler: function(){Ext.getCmp('message-box').hide();}
                                         },
                                     ],
                                     }
                                 ]
                            });
        box.show();
```